# Django 2.0: combine path and re_path got NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

Using `path` in project's `urls.py`, and using `re_path` in app's `urls.py`, I got the `NoReverseMatch` error, my project's `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', include('user.urls', namespace='user'))
]
```

My app's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/',
            views.activate_account, name='activate'),
]
```

I can't get the correct url, the error message:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': b'Mjc', 'token': '4tv-d4250012f57297ad82a6'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user\\/activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you need to decode the uuid before sending it to the url

like `uuid.decode()`

Comment: It works, but how can I get the `uid` from `uidb64`?

Comment: the place when you are using it, before putting it, just use that